# vhdl tristate output in lattice diamond

Tags: vhdl, lattice-diamond

i'm trying to write a module to read/write to a sram ic (CY7C1011CV33 -10ns), but I'm having a hard time outputting something to the inout port. I was able to make things work close enough to how I want, but now I have a different problem. When I add this module to my design I can synthesize, but when I try to design the map I get the following error:

> WARNING - Register MEMORY/Opin_11__I_0_i2 has a clock signal tied to GND.
>   WARNING - Register MEMORY/Opin_11__I_0_i3 has a clock signal tied to GND.
>   WARNING - Register MEMORY/Opin_11__I_0_i4 has a clock signal tied to GND.
>   WARNING - Register MEMORY/Opin_11__I_0_i5 has a clock signal tied to GND.
>   WARNING - Register MEMORY/Opin_11__I_0_i6 has a clock signal tied to GND.
>   WARNING - Register MEMORY/Opin_11__I_0_i7 has a clock signal tied to GND.
>   WARNING - Register MEMORY/Opin_11__I_0_i8 has a clock signal tied to GND.
>   WARNING - Register MEMORY/Opin_11__I_0_i9 has a clock signal tied to GND.
>   WARNING - Register MEMORY/Opin_11__I_0_i10 has a clock signal tied to GND.
>   WARNING - Register MEMORY/Opin_11__I_0_i11 has a clock signal tied to GND.
>   WARNING - Register MEMORY/Opin_11__I_0_i12 has a clock signal tied to GND.
>   WARNING - Register MEMORY/Opin_11__I_0_i1 has a clock signal tied to GND.
>   WARNING - EHXPLLJ 'OSCmain/PLLInst_0' cannot obtain FREQUENCY_PIN_CLKOP=260.000 when FREQUENCY_PIN_CLKI=133.000, CLKI_DIV=5, CLKFB_DIV=13, CLKOP_DIV=2.
>   ERROR - L6MUX21 MUX/i672/GATE has missing data input. Check for dangling nets or logic.
>   INFO - Errors found in user's design.  Output files not written. Check map report for more details.

this part used to work before, so when I find the problem I'll update here

update to the code and testbench added
update 2: newer version of the code added, almost working

new code:
this does what I want, more or less, I just need to adjust the timing but it synthesizes.

```html
---------------------------------------------------
-- Ainda sendo escrito
-- Vai comunicar com o SRAM CY7C1011CV33 -10ns
---------------------------------------------------

library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_UNSIGNED.ALL;


entity SRAM is
 generic(n: natural :=12 );
    Port ( 
   -- FPGA INTERNAL ----
   clk    : in STD_LOGIC; -- internal clock
   send    : in STD_LOGIC; -- low to send data
   get     : in STD_LOGIC; -- low to get data
   Ipin   : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (11 downto 0); -- data to send to sram
   Opin   : out  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (11 downto 0); -- data to send to fpga
   add    : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (16 downto 0);  -- sram address input
   drdy   : out std_logic;   -- data ready
   ---------------------------------------------
   -- To sram ----------------------------------
   ---------------------------------------------
            Address : out  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (16 downto 0); 
   Data : inout  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (11 downto 0);
   CE     : out STD_LOGIC;
   WE     : out STD_LOGIC;
   OE     : out STD_LOGIC;
   BHE     : out STD_LOGIC
   );
end SRAM;

architecture Behavioral of SRAM is
 signal clk_div : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (1 downto 0) := B"00";
 signal clk_PH : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (1 downto 0) := B"00";
 signal Zero : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (n-1 downto 0) := B"000000000000";
 -- for inout port
 signal tmpdata : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(11 downto 0);
 signal TMPCE   : STD_LOGIC := '1';
 signal TMPWE   : STD_LOGIC := '1';
 signal TMPOE   : STD_LOGIC := '1';
 signal TMPBHE  : STD_LOGIC := '1';
 signal TMPDRDY : STD_LOGIC := '1';
begin

    -- clock divider
    process (clk)
    begin
        if (rising_edge(clk) and (send ='0' or get = '0')) then
            clk_div <= clk_div + '1';
        end if;
    end process;  
 
 -- clock divider phase 90
    process (clk)
    begin
        if (falling_edge(clk) and (send ='0' or get = '0')) then
            clk_ph <= clk_ph + '1';
        end if;
    end process;   
 
    process(clk_div, clk_ph, clk)
 begin 
  -- WRITE TO SRAM
  if (send = '0') then
   Address <= add;
   tmpdata <= Zero;
   TMPCE  <= '0';
   TMPWE  <= '0'; 
   TMPOE  <= '1';
   TMPBHE <= '0';
   TMPdrdy <= '1';
   
   TMPCE  <= '1';
   TMPWE  <= '1'; 
   TMPOE  <= '1';
   TMPBHE <= '1';
   TMPdrdy <= '1';
   case clk_div is
    when b"00" =>
     TMPCE  <= '0';
     TMPWE  <= '0'; 
     TMPOE  <= '1';
     TMPBHE <= '0';
     TMPdrdy <= '1';
    when b"01" =>
     TMPCE  <= '0';
     TMPWE  <= '0'; 
     TMPOE  <= '1';
     TMPBHE <= '0';
     TMPdrdy <= '1';
    when others  =>
     TMPCE  <= '1';
     TMPWE  <= '1'; 
     TMPOE  <= '1';
     TMPBHE <= '1';
     TMPdrdy <= '1';
    end case;
    
   case clk_ph is
    --when  b"00" =>
     --tmpdata <= Ipin;
    when  b"01" =>
     tmpdata <= Ipin;
    when  b"10" =>
     tmpdata <= Ipin;
    when others  =>
     tmpdata <= Zero;
    end case;
   end if;
  -- READ FROM SRAM
  if (send = '1' and get ='0') then
   Address <= add;
   TMPCE  <= '0';
   TMPOE  <= '0'; 
   TMPBHE <= '0';
   TMPWE  <= '1';
   TMPDRDY <= '1';
   case clk_div is
    when  b"01" =>
     Opin <= data;
    
    when  b"10" =>
     Opin <= data;
     TMPDRDY <= '0';
    when others  =>
     TMPCE  <= '1';
     TMPWE  <= '1';
     TMPOE  <= '1';
     TMPBHE <= '1';
    end case;
  end if;
 end process; 
 
 Data <= tmpdata when send = '0' else (others => 'Z');
 CE  <= TMPCE;
 WE  <= TMPWE;
 OE  <= TMPOE;
 BHE <= TMPBHE;
 drdy <= TMPDRDY;
end Behavioral;
```

```
-- VHDL Test Bench Created from source file SRAM.vhd -- Wed May 30 21:37:25 2018

--
-- Notes: 
-- 1) This testbench template has been automatically generated using types
-- std_logic and std_logic_vector for the ports of the unit under test.
-- Lattice recommends that these types always be used for the top-level
-- I/O of a design in order to guarantee that the testbench will bind
-- correctly to the timing (post-route) simulation model.
-- 2) To use this template as your testbench, change the filename to any
-- name of your choice with the extension .vhd, and use the "source->import"
-- menu in the ispLEVER Project Navigator to import the testbench.
-- Then edit the user defined section below, adding code to generate the 
-- stimulus for your design.
-- 3) VHDL simulations will produce errors if there are Lattice FPGA library 
-- elements in your design that require the instantiation of GSR, PUR, and
-- TSALL and they are not present in the testbench. For more information see
-- the How To section of online help.  
--
LIBRARY ieee;
USE ieee.std_logic_1164.ALL;
USE ieee.numeric_std.ALL;

ENTITY testbench IS
END testbench;

ARCHITECTURE behavior OF testbench IS 

    COMPONENT SRAM
    PORT(
        clk : IN std_logic;
        send : IN std_logic;
        get : IN std_logic;
        Ipin : IN std_logic_vector(11 downto 0);
        add : IN std_logic_vector(16 downto 0);    
        Data : INOUT std_logic_vector(11 downto 0);      
        Opin : OUT std_logic_vector(11 downto 0);
        drdy : OUT std_logic;
        Address : OUT std_logic_vector(16 downto 0);
        CE : OUT std_logic;
        WE : OUT std_logic;
        OE : OUT std_logic;
        BHE : OUT std_logic
        );
    END COMPONENT;

    SIGNAL clk :  std_logic;
    SIGNAL send :  std_logic;
    SIGNAL get :  std_logic;
    SIGNAL Ipin :  std_logic_vector(11 downto 0);
    SIGNAL Opin :  std_logic_vector(11 downto 0);
    SIGNAL add :  std_logic_vector(16 downto 0);
    SIGNAL drdy :  std_logic;
    SIGNAL Address :  std_logic_vector(16 downto 0);
    SIGNAL Data :  std_logic_vector(11 downto 0);
    SIGNAL CE :  std_logic;
    SIGNAL WE :  std_logic;
    SIGNAL OE :  std_logic;
    SIGNAL BHE :  std_logic;

    constant delay : time := 10 ns;

BEGIN

-- Please check and add your generic clause manually
    uut: SRAM PORT MAP(
        clk => clk,
        send => send,
        get => get,
        Ipin => Ipin,
        Opin => Opin,
        add => add,
        drdy => drdy,
        Address => Address,
        Data => Data,
        CE => CE,
        WE => WE,
        OE => OE,
        BHE => BHE
    );

      send <= '0';
      get  <= '1';
      Ipin <= B"000011110000"; 
      add  <= B"00000000000000001";

-- *** Test Bench - User Defined Section ***
   tb : PROCESS
   BEGIN
      clk  <= '0';

      wait for delay;
      clk  <= '1';

      wait for delay;
      clk  <= '0';

      wait for delay;
      clk  <= '1';

      wait for delay;
      clk  <= '0';

      wait for delay;
      clk  <= '1';

      wait for delay;
      clk  <= '0';

      wait for delay;
      clk  <= '1';

   END PROCESS;
-- *** End Test Bench - User Defined Section ***

END;
```

I'm still learning how to VHDL and fpga so I imagine that there is quite a bit of errors on my whole thought process though this code.
here is a quick drawing of what I am trying to produce (when something goes high it just means something is being 'transmitted also add doesn't need to go low on the end):
[image]

Comment: You could enable VHDL-2008 in Diamond :). The VHDL line for a tri-state buffer is `Data <= tmpdata when send = '1' else (others => 'Z');`. This work in Diamond too.

Comment: thanks, I didn't know that I could enable VHDL-2008. thanks for your help

Comment: I just ran a simulation and I seem to have another problem(one i though I had escaped) tmpdata isn't being driven from this position: elsif(clk_div = b"00") then 
                if(falling_edge(clk))then
                    tmpdata <= Ipin;        
                end if;

Comment: You're problem can't be replicated (or seen) without a [mcve]. You're likely seeing the resolved `Data` value. A 'U' and any other std_logic value resolves to a 'U'. `Data` should have one driver assigning `Z`s while the other is driving ('Z' and any other non '-' resolves to the other value). Note the Cypress model DQ assignments with CE or OE false. The VHDL-1576 error is telling you a sequential conditional signal assignment is a -2008 feature (and you're not using  -2008 compliant mode or tools). Move the assignment outside the process.

Comment: There's a VHDL example for Bidirectional Buffers in the General HDL Practices section of the HDL Coding Guidelines.

Comment: thanks, I'll take a look. I changed the code to be the same as I now have and included a testbench